# Listar contactos de Whatsapp

Tags: java, android, whatsapp

Hay alguna forma de obtener los contactos que tienen Whatsapp entre todos los contactos obtenidos del teléfono?

Mis pruebas solo ha sido obtener obtener todos los contactos y obtener sus campos, para observar si había alguno "whatsapp...":

```
ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
    Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
            null, null, null, null);
```

y después recorro todos la filas obteniendo sus campos

```
String[] columnNames = cur.getColumnNames();

for (String columName: columnNames){
    int index = cur.getColumnIndex(columName);
    String value = cur.getString(index);
    Log.d(TAG, "columName: " + columName +" =" + value);
}
```

y de todos los nombres de campos, no puedo diferenciar ningún dato para determinar si lo tengo en whatsapp

No domino demasiado el tema de los contenedores de contenido, tal vez exista alguno exclusivo de whatasapp si está instalado...

¿Alguna sugerencia de como hacerlo?

Comment: Hola Webserveis. Qué es lo que has intentado? Por que no te salió lo intentado? Mira [ask] y [mcve] para mejorar tu pregunta. Tu pregunta de sugerencia se considera basado en opiniones o incluso muy amplia. Un saludo

Comment: Echa un vistazo a esto: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35448250/how-to-get-whatsapp-contacts-from-android

Comment: @Webserveis, que propiedad deseas listar, solo el nombre?

Comment: @Jorgesys, no no digamos he hecho debug para mostrar todos los nombres del campo, para ver si había alguno especifico o como empezar la búsqueda...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Esta es un forma de obtenerlos, mediante un [ContactsContract](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.html) para cuentas de tipo "Whatsapp", puedes obtener los datos en un cursor :

```
Cursor contactCursor = cr.query(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI, new String[]{ContactsContract.RawContacts._ID, ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTACT_ID}, ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE + "= ?", new String[]{"com.whatsapp"}, null);
```

Como ejemplo este método el cual puede retornar en un ArrayList datos como ID, Nombre, Numero de contacto y estatus:

```
private static final int CONTACT_ID = 0,  DISPLAY_NAME =  1 , NUMBER = 2 , STATUS = 3;
```

método:

```
        private  ArrayList<String> getContactNumbers(int datatype){
            ArrayList<String> contactData = new ArrayList<>();
            ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
            Cursor contactCursor = cr.query(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI, new String[]{ContactsContract.RawContacts._ID, ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTACT_ID}, ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE + "= ?", new String[]{"com.whatsapp"}, null);

            if (contactCursor != null) {
                if (contactCursor.getCount() > 0) {
                    if (contactCursor.moveToFirst()) {
                        do {
                           String contactId = contactCursor.getString(contactCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTACT_ID));
                            if (contactId != null) {
                                Cursor c = cr.query(
                                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                                        new String[]{ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID,
                                                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,
                                                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.STATUS},                                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?", new String[]{contactId}, null);

                                if (c != null) {
                                    c.moveToFirst();
                                    String data = "";
                                    switch (datatype){
                                       case CONTACT_ID:
                                           data = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID));
                                           break;
                                        case DISPLAY_NAME:
                                            data = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
                                            break;
                                        case NUMBER:
                                            data = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                                            break;
                                        case STATUS:
                                            data = String.valueOf(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.STATUS)));
                                        break;
                                        default:
                                        break;
                                    }
                                    c.close();
                                    contactData.add(data);

                                }
                            }
                        } while (contactCursor.moveToNext());
                        contactCursor.close();
                    }
                }
            }

            return contactData;
        }
```

Por ejemplo para obtener todos los números de los contactos se realizaría de esta forma:

```
    ArrayList<String> contactos =  getContactNumbers(NUMBER);
```

Puedes modificar este método para que en lugar de obtener un ArrayList de String obtenga un ArrayList de objetos Contacto que tenga como propiedades ID, Nombre, Numero de contacto, estatus o los datos que desees

Recordar es importante tener definidos los permisos:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS"/>
```

Comment: Una pregunta porque buscas los datos en ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone en vez de ContactsContract.RawContacts?

Comment: ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone son los campos que se obtienen que están almacenados en el cursor del tipo de contacto que previamente obtienes mediante ContactsContract.RawContacts, en este caso los "tipos de contacto" Whatsapp : ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE + "= ?", new String[]{"com.whatsapp"}